# How to write transaction in Mariadb?

Tags: mariadb, jdbi

using query " **BEGIN; INSERT INTO employee (id, name) VALUES (:id,:name); COMMIT ;**" to commit the transaction through java code and additionally setting id and name parameters but getting below error.
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=812) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO employee (id, name) VALUES (150,'150_abc'); COMMIT' at line 1

have tried with belwo query:
start transaction; INSERT INTO employee (id, name) VALUES (:id,:name); COMMIT ;
using MariaDb version 10.7.3

Answer (score 0):

you should try the following :

MOST IMPORTANT TO CONSIDER, IS TO SET THE AUTOCOMMIT TO FALSE, otherwise MariaDB will refuse not automatic transaction management.

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://192.0.2.1:3306?user=db_user&password=db_user_password")) {

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            try {
                try (PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test.accounts(first_name, last_name, email, amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

                    prep.setString(1, "John");
                    prep.setString(2, "Smith");
                    prep.setString(3, "john.smith@example.com");
                    prep.setDouble(4, 900.00);
                    prep.executeQuery();
                }

                try (PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE test.accounts SET amount = ? WHERE email = ?")) {

                    prep.setDouble(1, 1000.00);
                    prep.setString(2, "john.smith@example.com");
                    prep.executeQuery();
                }

                conn.commit();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                conn.rollback();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```